# OpenVPN server interface sharing issues on Windows Server 2019

Tags: networking, openvpn, windows-server

Let me explain my problem to you. I put OpenVPN on a Windows Server 2019. However I have a problem with the network interface sharing. When I restart the server. The sharing doesn't work anymore. I need to disable the sharing and reactivate it and restart the OpenVPN services for it to work. Would you have a solution to offer me ?

Comment: have you ever installed any update recently?

Comment: No, I don't install any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. You just have to follow this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/ics-not-work-after-computer-or-service-restart. I hope this answer can help someone.